# How to create variables inside a for loop to assign dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 2.7 and am creating some specific summary metrics by month from a dataframe. Each average (jan_avg_prod_count, feb_avg_prod_count, etc...) is then added to an output file.

```
My main df:

month_num     prod_desc    prod_count
01             A            52
01             B            43
01             C            38
02             A            21
02             B            24
02             c            18
```

What I am after is summarizing the average prod_count from the dataframe by month.  Right now, I am manually aggregating each month with the following and repeating for each month:

```
jan_df = df[df.month_num == '01']
jan_df = df.groupby(['prod_desc']).agg({'prod_count': np.mean})
jan_df = df.rename(columns = {'prod_count':'jan_avg_prod_count'})
```

What I want to do is put this in a loop so I only have one block of code. My approach is to loop through the range 1-12 and subset my main df by each month as above. However, I am stuck on how to create and assign the dataframes to a dynamic variable name.

I am trying to create a dictionary of the correct dataframes and then assign them.

```
month_dfs = {}
for x in range(1,13):
    month_dfs[x] = "%s_df" % calendar.month_abbr[x].lower()
    loop_month_num = '{num:02d}'.format(num = x)
    month_dfs[x] = df[df.month_num == loop_month_num]
```

The above generates a dictionary of correct values but the assignment to the subset dataframe does not work correctly.

If I print month_dfs I get what I expect:

```
jan_df
feb_df
mar_df
apr_df
may_df
jun_df
jul_df
aug_df
sep_df
oct_df
nov_df
dec_df
```

However, jan_df does not get created. Rather the month_dfs dictionary gets populated with the subset dataframes.

```
>>> month_dfs[x]
  month_num prod_desc prod_count
3        02         A         21
4        02         B         24
5        02         C         18
```

I understand what I am doing is not correct. I'm just not sure of how to get the monthly dataframes created.
Any advice or new direction is appreciated.

Comment: *"does not work correctly"* - what exactly does that mean? Could you provide examples?

Comment: I cleaned up my example and added some output.

Comment: What's wrong with `df.groupby(['month_num', 'prod_desc'])`?

Comment: The groupby approach does not produce separate metrics for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing a pivot_table on your `df` and obtain another dataframe with column names `jan_avg_prod_count, feb_avg_prod_count`, etc... is faster than loop and easier to use than dictionary.

```
In [35]: df['month'] = df.month_num.map(lambda n: calendar.month_abbr[int(n)].lower())+'_avg_prod_count'

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
  month_num prod_desc  prod_count               month
0        01         A          52  jan_avg_prod_count
1        01         B          43  jan_avg_prod_count
2        01         C          38  jan_avg_prod_count
3        02         A          21  feb_avg_prod_count
4        02         B          24  feb_avg_prod_count
5        02         C          18  feb_avg_prod_count

In [37]: pt = df.pivot_table(columns='month',index='prod_desc',values='prod_count', aggfunc=sum)

In [38]: pt
Out[38]: 
month      feb_avg_prod_count  jan_avg_prod_count
prod_desc                                        
A                          21                  52
B                          24                  43
C                          18                  38
```

If you want to get 'jan_avg_prod_count', you can use `pt` like a dictionary:

```
In [39]: pt['jan_avg_prod_count']
Out[39]: 
prod_desc
A            52
B            43
C            38
Name: jan_avg_prod_count, dtype: int64
```

which gives you a pandas Series.

Loop should be avoided if you can because it's slow.

Comment: I like your approach and am trying it out. I get the following error though: TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: Thank you. This last pivot_table statement got exactly what I needed. pt = df.pivot_table(cols='month',values='prod_count', aggfunc=mean)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits your use case but you might want to make dictionary of dataframes where each key is the 'month'. So dataframes['jan'] gives you the dataframe for January.. etc..

If that will work then you could do something like...

```
months = ['jan','feb','mar', ...]
dataframes = {month:pandas.DataFrame(df[df['month_num']==index]) \
              for month,index in zip(months, range(1,13)}
```